# NVD3.js: how to config x axis or y axis values

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3.js for a graphy but I am stuck with how to set values on x axis or y axis values.

my question is:

1.how to change the default values on x or y axis by using my own values?
2.how to change the amounts of the values that is on axis?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qENax.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `chart.forceX = [min,max]` and `chart.forceY=[min,max]` to manually set a static or dynamic axis values. You can change the increment of axis values with `chart.xAxis.tickValues(['1','2','3'])`, and similarly for the y axis tick values.